Access VBA For Loop throwing error of "No Current Record" after 1 iteration of code
I have an Access database with a list of supervisors and employees. I would like to add a specific number of task records (number housed in a config table) for each employee. I loop through the table to get a list of supervisors, then loop through the table again for a list of employees (stored in separate record sets) - all working fine.
When I add the For Loop to the code, it will add the 1st supervisor and 1 task for each employee, then when it goes to move to the next iteration and add a second task for each employee, I get the error:

Run-time error '3021': No current record.

Something isn't jiving and I can't figure out why - code snip is below:
gSQL = "SELECT AssocID, Position, StatusCodeID FROM tblHistory WHERE (((tblHistory.Position) In (SELECT ConfigLongDesc FROM ref_Config WHERE ConfigShortDesc In ('Supervisors'))) AND tblHistory.StatusCodeID = '3')"

Set gRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(gSQL)
...
    If gRST.RecordCount > 0 Then
        gRST.MoveFirst

        Do Until gRST.EOF
            aSQL = "SELECT AssocID, Position, StatusCodeID FROM tblHistory WHERE (((tblHistory.Position) In (SELECT ConfigLongDesc FROM ref_Config WHERE ConfigShortDesc In ('Employees'))) AND tblHistory.StatusCodeID = '3')"

            Set aRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(aSQL)

            If aRST.RecordCount > 0 Then
                aRST.MoveFirst

                myCadence = DLookup("[ConfigLongDesc]", "ref_Config", "[ConfigShortDesc] = 'Frequency'")

                Do Until aRST.EOF
                    For i = 0 To myCadence

                        Debug.Print aRST!AssocID
                        aRST.MoveNext
                    Next i
                Loop
            End If
            gRST.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
Else
    Exit Function
End If

Right now I am just printing the results to the immediate window, it will add the record set information after the issue with the error is fixed.

You have aRST.MoveNext within a for loop without checking for EOF. You need If aRST.EOF Then Exit For Else aRST.MoveNext End If

@BartMcEndree I never even saw that. I've obviously looked at this code too much. It's running through now but I'm getting 3 task adds for each instead of 2 that is the number in myCandence. Any ideas?

Include i in your debug.Print.  You then might see i=0 AssocID=123, i=1 AssocID=456, i=2 AssocID=789. You might prefer For i = 1 To myCadence

It makes no sense to have two nested loops over the same Recordset. If you want to limit the number of loops, you can do that directly in the Do Until loop: Do Until aRST.EOF Or myCadence <0 and then decrement myCadence inside the loop and drop the For-loop.

I don't see how those SQL statements can even work because of quote mark in In "(SELECT. Did not even provide complete code - what is the If that goes with the final End If? Why not ConfigShortDesc = 'Employees' instead of In?

Sample data and desired result as formatted text tables could be helpful.

You want every supervisor to have task records for every employee?

Your DLookup does not make sense to me. The same value is retrieved in each loop.

I noticed that your DLookup is returning a value from a column called "ConfigLongDesc"... is "Desc" short for "Description" and therefore this value is a string? IF so, when you assign that string to myCadence, and use myCadence to initialise the upper value of your For Loop (For i = 0 To myCadence), is it trying to do 0 to [some string value] rather than 0 to [some number value]?

There is no For block shown in code. Did you mean Do Until since you show 2 of those?

The phrases Do Until aRST.EOF and For i = 0 To myCadence could be in the wrong order.  
The execution of the sourcecode reaches For i = 0 and starts executing aRST.MoveNext, at least until aRST.EOF, at which point the execution has no problem going beyond aRST.EOF...  The only test performed is on I <= myCadence, hence the execution goes beyond aRST.EOF ... 
I would suggest the following:
For i = 0 To myCadence
    aRST.MoveFirst
    Do Until aRST.EOF
        Debug.Print aRST!AssocID
        aRST.MoveNext
    Loop
Next i

